# What happens to force, impulse and time of a collision as velocity is doubled?

Tags: forces, kinematics, collision

If an object collides with a massive wall (massive enough that it would hardly move) at velocity V, it will have force F acting for time T, giving impulse of I. If you increased the collision velocity to 2V, would time be T, 1/2T or 2T? Would impulse be 2I or 4I? Would the force be 2F or 4F? Why?

Comment: Hint: impulse is equal to overall change in momentum.

Answer (score 1):

Impulse will be $2I$, as that is just change in momentum, which is proportional to $V$. Let's say the object is a mass attached to a spring, and that it collides elastically with the wall.  In this case, during the time the spring is in contact with the wall, the mass undergoes half a cycle of simple harmonic motion, whose period depends on the spring constant and the mass, but is independent of amplitude, and so independent of $V$.  Since $T$ remains unchanged and $I$ doubles, $F$ doubles as well.